# Composer Installation Problem

Tags: cache, composer

Cannot create cache directory /home/rukon/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/rukon/.cache/composer/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
##This Shown On My Terminal, what can I do now?
I am using Ubuntu 18.04.
When I was given the command "composer" to check if the composer correctly installed or not then it showed me it installed but at the beginning it is shown above the line

Comment: Which distro of Linux and which version? What was the command you typed to get this error? What were you trying to do? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1319340/edit) and add all these new information to the question.

Comment: It's best to post all the return from a terminal command, at times it sheds more information that we might be able to help you better.
Instead of typing all the code listed here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35874482/cannot-create-cache-directory-or-directory-is-not-writable-proceeding-withou][1] see if any of that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to fix the issue:

> $ sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.composer

Good Luck

Comment: After giving this command it shows now no such file or directory